# CAMEL - Channel Closed exception not caught using onException

Tags: apache-camel

I am opening this question as I didn't find any answer to problem in the web.

I have used camel to implement a TCP/IP server and I have defined a route like this:

```
    from("netty4:tcp://0.0.0.0:3510")
    .to("file:target/outbox");
```

and I have a client which sends data to this server. When I disconnect this client I can see in my logs this exception:

```
    [Camel (camel-client) thread #0 - NettyEventExecutorGroup] WARN  o.a.c.component.netty4.NettyConsumer - Closing channel as an exception was thrown from Netty. Caused by: [java.io.IOException - an existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host]
```

My problem is that I am not able to catch this exception using onException clause.

```
    onException(IOException.class)
    .log("Exception: ${body}")
    .handled(true)
    .process(new ExceptionProcessor());
```

The program does not stop but I want to catch it to handle when the client is disconnected.
Note that I can catch other exceptions which are thrown inside my route.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot handle it as exception, because exception is already catched in netty and logged. This exception is not propagated from netty to netty component.

The solution is a bit tricky. You can extend SimpleChannelInboundHandler and override method `channelInactive` as described in [How can I detect network disconnection in Apache Camel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41940482/how-can-i-detect-network-disconnection-in-apache-camel).
In this custom handler you can set custom properties on exchange with additional information, which is relevant in your application.

Comment: Thank you very much Bedla. I managed to catch the exception finally using the solution you described.